# How to determine all files that were created by a command

Tags: files, command

I want to know what files were created during execution of some shell command.

Comment: You can strace them. man strace. `strace -s 200 -f my_script.sh 2>&1grep -E '(open|creat)'`

Comment: @peterh, that is at least something... this can give me a list of files that was USED by script... i'm still looking how i can determine only CREATED files...

Comment: Not true, the grep command filters out the file creation calls for you.

Comment: @peterh, thanks for your help, but using proposed command on this script "cat test.txt > test_copy.txt" will output opening test.txt alongside with alot of other system crap... So at least it's something, but i can't see any way i can achive my goal.

Comment: 1: The crap is not so crappy, but yes, also not trivial. There aren't noo many system calls, it is relatively easy to learn them. 2: much simpler way doesn't exist, because your question indirectly means that you want to follow all commands called by your script, thus you need to trace this on the system call level.

Comment: This may do more than what you need, but it's included in many distros: [checkinstall](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CheckInstall)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, Hey, "checkinstall" contain [installwatch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installwatch) application wich claims to do exactly what i need. Source code looks really cryptic, and looks like it patches glibc functions, so it not work with some software(GNU CoreUtils). But i guess it will give me what i want.

Comment: You can add some useful options to strace: `strace -e open,creat -f -o /tmp/out myscript...` to just trace open and creat, to trace children, and to output to a separate file.